# Передать Json в модальное окно (или нет? Какие варианты?)

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Есть такой код: https://jsfiddle.net/vh88u4uh/

```
function newModal() {
    var newModal = `
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  `;
  $('body').append(newModal);
}

$('button').on('click', newModal);
```

и такая кнопка

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

И есть куча таких кнопок на странице, хочу, чтобы каждая открывала свое модальное окно, в котором будет содержимое, полученное по опр. ссылке (например /jobinfo.php?id=XXX).
Подскажите, как это сделать, пожалуйста (я новичок).

Comment: а в чём вопрос? как получить строку `newModal`?

Comment: @qwabra я ничего в js не понимаю. я хочу, чтобы содержимое в этой функции бралось из файла /jobinfo.php?id=XXX. И при этом у меня на странице много таких однотипных кнопок. Как заставить все это работать?

Comment: Соответственно, по каждой кнопке свое содержимое в модальном окне хочу

Comment: "я ничего в js не понимаю. я хочу, чтобы.." - интересный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, тогда, возможно, подойдет такой алгоритм:

1. при клике на кнопку через ajax делаем запрос страницы
   /jobinfo.php?id=XXX с нужным id (можно брать через атрибут data,
   соответственно нужно этот атрибут прописать для каждой кнопки)
2. в ответ получаем нужный html код для модального окна и вставляем этот 
   код в оболочку модального окна
3. вызываем модальное окно

Что бы сделать, нужно подтянуть знания по [Основы XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest), [Добавление и удаление узлов DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document), [Атрибуты и DOM-свойства](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties).

Попробуйте сделать. Если не получится, [выложите в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) уже кусок Вашего кода с которым у Вас возникли проблемы.